# How to return null when not matched (Opposite of nullif function)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get null when both exp are not matched like nullif(exp1,exp2) will return null when same and return first exp when not same.

i have tried with the help of sub query or creating functions but need a simple, easy, standard way out.

```
select * from table
where service_type = 'X3' 
or (1 <> (select nvl(min(1),2) from table where service_type = 'X3') 
and service_type is null)
```

This query returns my desire result but i need not to use a sub query.

table have data like

```
service_type
------------
X4
X3
null
```

I want to get if service_type match X3 value returns X3 but if not matched like X5 then return null to match null record.

When service_type = 'X3'

```
service_type
------------
X3
```

When service_type = 'X5' or any other like 'X%' will return null

```
service_type
------------
null
```

Comment: Add some more sample data and also _specify_ the expected result (formatted text here too.)

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQLite?

Comment: Oracle database

Answer (score 1):

what about case when

```
select case when service_type='x3' then service_type else null end
from table_name
```

Comment: then i have to make query some thing like this

Comment: select * from table
where service_type = 'X3' 
or ((select case when service_type='x3' then service_type else null end
from table_name) is null and service_type is null))

Comment: Which is also a headache to manage i need like not nullif(exp1,exp2) returns null when not match inline query

Comment: @ShahbazAli could you please share sample data and expected output in question or dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0

Comment: i have re edited or you can try with :
create table tbl(service_type varchar2(20));
insert into tbl values('X3'),insert into tbl values('X4'),insert into tbl values(null)

Comment: @ShahbazAli https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=86bd1697d1268750017edf336f912a17 can you please check this link. does you find something like this

Comment: @ShahbazAli yes it is returned null

Comment: try this:
select * from tbl
where service_type = 'X5' 
or (1 <> (select nvl(min(1),2) from tbl where service_type = 'X5') 
and service_type is null)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193377/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-shahbaz-ali).

Comment: if you are not getting my point then add one more column like service_type varchar,product_type
and insert into tbl ('X3','B1');insert into tbl ('X4','B2');insert into tbl (null,'B3');

Comment: with your case =>
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7f3e2839152b9314247a035be6b4891e

Comment: If u get understand then i want to avoid use of sub query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a subquery for the logic you actually want to implement:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.service_type = :value or
      (t.service_type is null and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.service_type = :value)
      );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by service_type) as cnt
      from t
      where service_type = :value or service_type is null
     ) t
where service_type = :value or
      (cnt = 0 and service_type is null);
```

Comment: I have already done with sub query is there any other way too ?